# making icons using border-size property

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-grid

I have never even heard of CSS border-width property having multiple values, let alone seen it used this way.

ng-grid uses border-width to *make* arrow icons - like this:

```
border-width:5px 8.7px 5px 0;
```

I do not know whether this is ng-grid-specific or whether it is a general property, available in any setting.

Check this plunker out:
http://plnkr.co/edit/50vJrs

Never mind all the JavaScript, just play with the CSS, specifically the border-width values in style.css.

Am I out-of-the-loop CSS-wise?

Comment: No it's something that's been around for some time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does this CSS triangle shape work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work)

Comment: Wow. I had no idea. So, what advantages does this incur? I cna see how it's a useful alternative to gifs, but what about font icons, such as font awesome?

Comment: Triangles are just the start although they all use the same technique. [**Shapes of CSS @ CSS-Tricks**](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/). Advantages include no extra http request and no images. It's not a real substitute for icons / fonts though...just nice to have in your toolbelt.

Comment: With CSS you're not out of the loop, you're outside the box.